# Using rules how to redirect to a url + element id

Tags: rules, workflows

After saving a node, I am redirecting to another form using rules.

I want to be able to append this value "field_article[und][0][nid]" to the url that I am sending to.  This corresponds to a select list id. Basically, I want this id appended to the url when I redirect.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You can use token from `Replacement Patterns` list. Token will be something like `[node:field_node_ref]`.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[image: Screenshot]

The Rules module provide PHP Evaluation for the action "Page Redirect". You can get the field value using PHP code and append it to the URL. Refer attached Screenshot.

Note: Before providing the value for URL, make sure that value Exists.